# Animations and complex graphics required?

Tags: gui-design, user-expectation, user-centered-design, user-feedback

Hey guys I need some suggestions, I am developing a domain website on health care where   specialists surgeons doctors who treats specific health problem. Is having animations,sliders, gradients makes users(patients in this case)  difficult to use the site? Please suggest should I go with simple ui Or having all the above is ok for this.

Comment: What will these animations and complex graphics be used for? If it is for information display then simple is generally a safe starting point for conveying information.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail the purpose of the site? It's not clear what the role of "specialists surgeons doctors who treats specific health problem" is. It's not clear how patients will be using the site. It's not clear what the purpose of "animations,sliders, gradients" will be. Is the site intended to be an educational resource? An EMR with patient portal?

Answer (score 2):

Using the animations design-wise and interaction wise makes the patients (users) to feel more confident and easy going, but using those must serve a purpose rather than just gimmicks then using those features gives more sense.